# Compare input value to string in IF statement C# ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, honeypot

So i'm trying to adjust a small piece of code (i'm not known with C# ASP.NET Razor) to where i can compare an user value input to my own string like so:

```
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="hello" required>

string strTest = Library.StripHtml(Request["test"]).ToString();

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTest)){
            client.Send(mail);
        }
```

to something like

```
if(test.input == "hello"){
                client.Send(mail);
            }
```

The idea behind it is to make the field required so that if the value is changed the mail wont send (honeypot method). I guess most bots simply don't fill the forms without an requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks some information or code. The input has an id **test** but the condition is using **strTest** so there is some other code involved in parsing the input.

Assuming that you can still use the **strTest** variable in your new condition, why not simply check that variable against your predefined string?

```
if(strTest == "hello"){
                client.Send(mail);
            }
```

Comment: You're right. I've adjusted my post with an extra line. I'll give it a shot!